# Center a dialog in Pharo 3.0

Tags: user-interface, smalltalk, pharo

If I 'do it' in a Workspace in Pharo 3.0

```
self confirm: 'test'
```

then the dialog is modal but no way to make it centered. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You and do this but in more complex way.

First of all you can try to do something with Spec like:

```
(LabelModel new text: 'test') openDialogWithSpec centered
```

But here you also have to handle the result of a dialog separately and so on (defined during the setup of the model).

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is *by design*. The dialog is not modal, it is modal to the workspace
you started it in. There are therefore two good locations for the dialog: close to the
workspace and close to the cursor position (hand). Center of the screen is not as good.
Pharo uses close to the cursor position.

If you take a look at the implementors of confirm: and follow up to

```
UITheme>>questionWithoutCancelIn: aThemedMorph text: aStringOrText title: aString
```

you can create something similar and use a variant of

```
Morph>>openModal:
```

using the center of the screen instead.